# How to do an MCMC fitting using only a subset of variables of a function?

Tags: python, mcmc, model-fitting, emcee

I have a function that has many parameters/variables. For simplicity we can assume it is f(a,b,c)=a + b * x + c * x**2, where the parameters "a", "b" and "c" can either be fixed parameters or variables I want to fit.
I can fit f(a,b,c) with the three parameters simultaneously without problem. The issue is when I want to fix "b" and fit "a" and "c", or fix "b" and "c" and just fit "a". The motivation is that in physical systems some of these parameters can be known and therefore I can focus on fitting just the other ones (or maybe I don't have enough data points to fit many parameters and I prefer to fix some and let free only the most relevant ones).

This is a version of a code that works, fixing to fit all parameters:

```
import numpy as np
import emcee
import corner
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# True parameters of the function
true_a = 1.0
true_b = 2.0
true_c = 0.5

# Generate synthetic data with noise
np.random.seed(42)
x_data = np.linspace(-8, 10, 50)
y_true = true_a + true_b * x_data + true_c * x_data**2
y_data = y_true + np.random.normal(scale=0.05, size=len(x_data))

# Define the quadratic function
def f(x, a, b, c):
    return a + b * x + c * x**2

# Define the log-likelihood function
def log_likelihood(params, x, y, y_err):
    a, b, c = params
    model = f(x, a, b, c)
    return -0.5 * np.sum((y - model)**2 / y_err**2)

# Define the log-prior function
def log_prior(params):
    # Uniform priors for a, b, c
    if all(-10.0 < p < 10.0 for p in params):
        return 0.0
    return -np.inf

# Define the log-posterior function
def log_posterior(params, x, y, y_err):
    lp = log_prior(params)
    if not np.isfinite(lp):
        return -np.inf
    return lp + log_likelihood(params, x, y, y_err)

# Perform MCMC fitting
ndim = 3  # Number of parameters (a, b, c)
nwalkers = 50
nsteps = 2000
burnin = nsteps // 3  # Burn-in steps (1/3 of the total steps)

# Initialize walkers with random values around the true parameters
initial_params = [true_a, true_b, true_c]
per = 0.1
initial_pos = [initial_params + per * np.random.randn(ndim) for _ in range(nwalkers)]

# Set up the MCMC sampler
sampler = emcee.EnsembleSampler(nwalkers, ndim, log_posterior, args=(x_data, y_data, 0.5))

# Run the sampler with burn-in
sampler.run_mcmc(initial_pos, nsteps, progress=True)

# Get the samples after burn-in
samples = sampler.get_chain(discard=burnin, flat=True)
```

Now this is my attempt to define which parameters to fit using as an argument a dictionary (though it might not be the right approach?)

```
import numpy as np
import emcee
import corner
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# True parameters of the function
true_a = 1.0
true_b = 2.0
true_c = 0.5

# Generate synthetic data with noise
np.random.seed(42)
x_data = np.linspace(-8, 10, 50)
y_true = true_a + true_b * x_data + true_c * x_data**2
y_data = y_true + np.random.normal(scale=0.05, size=len(x_data))

# Define the function
def f(x, params):
    a = params.get('a', 0.0)
    b = params.get('b', 0.0)
    c = params.get('c', 0.0)
    return a + b * x + c * x**2

# Define the log-likelihood function
def log_likelihood(params, x, y, y_err):
    model = f(x, params)
    return -0.5 * np.sum((y - model)**2 / y_err**2)

# Define the log-prior function
def log_prior(params):
    # Uniform priors for a, b, c
    a = params.get('a', 0.0)
    b = params.get('b', 0.0)
    c = params.get('c', 0.0)
    if all(-10.0 < p < 10.0 for p in [a, b, c]):
        return 0.0
    return -np.inf

# Define the log-posterior function
def log_posterior(params, x, y, y_err):
    lp = log_prior(params)
    if not np.isfinite(lp):
        return -np.inf
    return lp + log_likelihood(params, x, y, y_err)


# Initialize walkers with random values around the true parameters
nwalkers = 50
initial_params = {'a': true_a, 'b': true_b, 'c': true_c} # here I would like to have any combination of parameters, not necessarily all three
per = 0.1
initial_pos = [{key: val + per * np.random.randn() for key, val in initial_params.items()} for _ in range(nwalkers)]

# Perform MCMC fitting
ndim = len(initial_params)  # Number of parameters 
nsteps = 2000
burnin = nsteps // 3  # Burn-in steps (1/3 of the total steps)


# Set up the MCMC sampler
sampler = emcee.EnsembleSampler(nwalkers, ndim, log_posterior, args=(x_data, y_data, 0.05))

# Run the sampler with burn-in
sampler.run_mcmc(initial_pos, nsteps, progress=True)

# Get the samples after burn-in
samples = sampler.get_chain(discard=burnin, flat=True)
```

But when it runs it says:
---> 63 sampler.run_mcmc(initial_pos, nsteps, progress=True)
ValueError: incompatible input dimensions (1, 50)

I would really appreciate feedback on how to address this.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using the [bilby](https://lscsoft.docs.ligo.org/bilby/index.html) package, which provides a wrapper to emcee. With bilby you can set any fixed parameters of the model to have [`DeltaFunction`](https://lscsoft.docs.ligo.org/bilby/api/bilby.core.prior.analytical.DeltaFunction.html#bilby.core.prior.analytical.DeltaFunction) priors. For example:

```
import numpy as np

from bilby import run_sampler
from bilby.core.likelihood import GaussianLikelihood
from bilby.core.prior import Uniform, DeltaFunction


# model function
def model(x, a, b, c):
    return a + b * x + c * x**2


# True parameters of the function
true_a = 1.0
true_b = 2.0
true_c = 0.5

# Generate synthetic data with noise
np.random.seed(42)
x_data = np.linspace(-8, 10, 50)
y_true = model(x_data, true_a, true_b, true_c)

y_err = 0.05
y_data = y_true + np.random.normal(scale=y_err, size=len(x_data))

# set the Gaussian likelihood
likelihood = GaussianLikelihood(x_data, y_data, model, sigma=y_err)

# set the priors (uniform on a and b, but fixed for c)
prior = {
    "a": Uniform(-10, 10, "a", latex_label="$a$"),
    "b": Uniform(-10, 10, "b", latex_label="$b$"),
    "c": DeltaFunction(true_c, "c"),  # c is fixed at the true value
}

nwalkers = 50
nsteps = 2000
burnin = nsteps // 3

results = run_sampler(
    likelihood=likelihood,
    priors=prior,
    sampler="emcee",
    nwalkers=50,
    nsteps=2000,
    nburn=burnin,
    save=False,
)

# a pandas DataFrame containing the posterior samples
samples = results.posterior

# plot the posterior samples (for the non-fixed parameters) on a corner plot
results.plot_corner()
```

The output plot (by default saved into a directory called `outdir`) is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback! It seems to be an interesting solution. I was worried about performance if exploring unnecessary parameters, but I am not sure of how using delta priors will impact effectively. I will play a bit with this to check how it goes and get familiar with the package, but I am optimistic about going in this direction :)

Comment: If you need help, bilby has decent documentation https://lscsoft.docs.ligo.org/bilby/index.html and other information about support can be found at https://git.ligo.org/lscsoft/bilby/-/blob/master/README.rst, such as using the [bilby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bilby) tag here on SO.